# Jquery Typeahead Bloodhound is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, bloodhound

I would like to use the javascript typeahead bloodhound but it's not working properly with a remote.

Here is my Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var clubs = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function () {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace;
        },
        queryTokenizer: function () {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace;
        },

        remote: {
            url: "{{ url('club/listall') }}"+'/%QUERY%',
            filter: function(searchClubs) {
                console.log(searchClubs);
                return searchClubs;
            },
            wildcard: "%QUERY%"
        },
    });

        $(".club-search").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            source: clubs.ttAdapter(),
            name: 'clubsList',
            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Aucun club trouvé.</div></div>'
                ],
                header: [
                    '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
                ],
                suggestion: function (data) {
                    return '<a href="{{ url('club') }}' + '/' + data.id + '" class="list-group-item"><span class="row">' +
                                '<span class="avatar">' +
                                    '<img src="{{asset('/')}}' + blason + '">' +
                                "</span>" +
                                '<span class="name">' + data.name + '<br><small style="color:grey;">(Ligue ' + data.league_name + ')</small></span>' +
                            "</span>"
          }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But its not working completely properly... In general, it finds results, but I'll give u an example of a search query. One possible query is "montagnarde". I'll give you the result for every letter. Typing:

```
m --> lot of results
mo --> lot of results
mon --> lot of results
mont --> lot of results
monta --> lot of results
montag --> lot of results
montagn --> lot of results
montagna --> no result
montagnar --> finds only "J.S. MONTAGNARDE"
montagnard --> finds only "J.S. MONTAGNARDE"
montagnarde --> finds only "J.S. MONTAGNARDE" and "LA MONTAGNARDE"
montagnarde i --> finds only "U.S. MONTAGNARDE INZINZAC"
```

And the `console.log(searchClubs)` gives me different result.

Does anybody see where is the problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I was using twitter/typeahead.js version 0.11.1 and unfortunately this version was not maintened anymore.

We have to use : corejavascript/typeahead.js version 1.1.1